# How to load image in picturebox dynamically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, picturebox

I need to load an image to a picturebox.

The image name is from the database.

```
 data[14].ToString() = 20131213.jpg
```

This code below is not working for me, instead it only shows a messagebox with the path of the photo..

```
 try
   {
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\ORS\uploads\photos" +  data[14].ToString() + "");
   }
 catch (Exception ex)
   {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
```

StackTrace = `" at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement)\r\n   at System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename)\r\n   at PSPC.RECRUIT.RE010_1.RE010_1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\\Users\\Quen\\Desktop\\Files\\Sour...`

Comment: Are you saying that the code you pasted here doesn't work? What is the issue?

Comment: Its possible that you are missing a "\" after the word photos unless that is in the database field you are returning

Comment: Tried it but still not working.. but thanks! i really forgot that "\"..

Comment: Do you get an exception? More information on the actual problem would be helpful! (For example: does the image have an extension when pulled from the database?)

Comment: Thanks! Could you be so kind as to paste the entire message and stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't really enough to go off of to answer specifically but there are a few common mistakes when loading images that can cause the code not to work:

- **The file name or path isn't correct**. I recommend putting the file name into a string variable, then using the debugger to copy that name and pasting into a start -> run box. This can be really helpful in figuring out how your file name/path is wrong.
- **The file isn't valid or isn't properly formatted**. This happens if you accidentally renamed a file or if the file just isn't a .NET recognized picture (as an example, layered TIFF images edited in Photoshop will not open in .NET). There are limitations on GDI+ image formats and types so you need to be really aware of those.
- **File access is denied**. You can get this even if the file exists if your program is running as a standard user account and the file is somewhere in a system folder. If you need to load this file you will need to add an application manifest to run your process with elevated privileges.
- **File in use elsewhere** you can get this even if you don't have the file open elsewhere because opening a bitmap without disposing it can leave the file in use. 99% of the time you can fix this issue by opening the bitmap in a "using" statement. NOTE: You can't use this if the image is tied to a form, because disposing the image will cause your form to crash. Dispose once you have removed the image from the form. An example of the using syntax looks like:

  using (Image x = Bitmap.FromFile(fileName)) {
      // code here that uses the image
   }
- **Out of memory exception** - you get this if you are opening an image that is too large or if you are low on system memory. Note that .NET processes get less memory to run anyways so you are really limited to "normal" sized images.
- **Parameter is not valid** - this is the toughest to troubleshoot but it usually comes down to any number of things such as you are asking too much of the GDI+ imaging engine by allocating too large of an image.

I don't know which of these is the problem here but I suspect if you go through this list it should (sooner or later) solve your issue. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

The Image File may be missing in the path. Please verify